# Attribute inspector for buttons has no background color

Tags: menu

Sorry but looks a simple question. In the attribute inspector menu of all my buttons the background color option menu/property disappeared in Main storyboard. I cannot change the color. I can change the text color, the shadow color, the background gives only the option of images but no color?? I rebooted xcode, and the MacBook as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. On the attribute inspector at the very bottom there is the view section. On the right of the View there was missing "show" word, looks like a bug and that's why I have not seen that I could expand the view. Now that I expanded it I can hide and show with this right button and the keyword show is there again.